# How to add a 'link back to homepage button' in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build my first blog webpage.

The code I wrote so far at the bottom of the question.

I wish it has a function when I click "my name" or "Home" it can turns to the very beginning main page. And when I click "Blog", it can link to the area where has picture or word contains.

However, so far my code does not have such function, instead, they just display as words (cannot click).

This is the template I tried to followed

And after comparing it, I find that I need to have **href: /** in order to make them as **button**. And also I realise their link is for example "https://www.personname.com/".

However, it makes me feels like that I should first has a personal webpage in order to put that link as a **back to home page button**. But...that is what I am doing, I am trying to build a webpage...

I tired add the code below and it links to a wrong position. :(

```
<a href="/">
                "Home"
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
```

[image]

I also tried to have a **button** feature, but it display as this grey trangle box in the picture and cannot click as well.

**How can I fix this problem?**

[image]

And below are the code I wrote so far

Comment: Generally, websites are run on web servers, not as individual files on file systems. So, a site like Stack Overflow runs on a server and when the location "/" is requested, the server interprets that as "the root of the website" (i.e., the home page). Since you're running the page using `file://` rather than `http://`, that doesn't work. Instead, just put the name of the file (e.g., index.html) in the `href` attribute. That will work in both places.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for explaining! How to link to another page of blog? And link to a picture? I saw others' blog are all **style="background-image：url('/img/header-slides/bg.jpg')"** In my case, which URL should I put here? If I have local pictures. Should I first upload them to somewhere online?

Comment: That's a whole different round of questions. Sounds like you could do with some tutorials on HTML and CSS. Linking to another page; put the name of the other page's file in the `href`. Link to a picture; put the name of the image file in the `href`. Sensing a pattern? :) If you ever want to share this stuff with other people, you'll need to get some kind of web server hosing, where you'll upload the HTML, CSS, JS, image, and any other files. That's beyond what this question is, and likely covered by the tutorials on creating a website you should research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [named anchor tags](http://www.tagindex.net/html/link/a_name.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20a%20link,element%20is%20set%20as%20follows.&text=Anchor%20names%20must%20be%20unique%20within%20a%20document.) to get this behavior.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a name="top"></a>
<a href="#top">Home</a>
<a href="#blog">Blog</a>

<section style="height: 100vh">
  <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
</section>

<section style="height: 100vh">
  <a name="blog"></a>
  <h1> Blog </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <a href="#top">Back to Top</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with detailed example and link. One more question, If I have local pictures. Should I first upload them to somewhere online before add into HTML? I.e. What **href** should I write then? (I saw others using **style="background-image：url('/img/header-slides/bg.jpg')"** But turnd out this is also a link such as **www.personname.come/pictures** which I cannot use )

Comment: its hard to say because that depends on how you are serving the files. The browser is for good reason not allowed to simply look into the users file system. So usually the files are served by a server. If and only if the files are served from the same server as your HTML page, you could write it like you tried `/img/header-slides/bg.jpg`. If its served from somewhere else you need to give the full url, including the server name where the files are served i,e,  `https://my-file-server/my-picutre.png`.

Comment: try using this until you understand it better -> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer . So you can focus on building stuff. When its time for hosting and such you can look more into it. https://pages.github.com/  is a great start.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something in the class on the 'a' element to make the link not clickable. Try to do it this way:

```
<a href="~/">"Home"
     <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! Just tried and update the picture in question part. It links to a wrong place...(link to my local /C)

Comment: code updated. I added the '~' character to the href property